# Extract bitmaps from Win98 SOL.EXE

Tags: windows, extract, bitmaps

I installed Windows 98 in a Virtualbox with the games. Then I sent myself the game Solitaire (SOL.EXE). Now I have SOL.EXE on Windows 7 and it actually runs. But I just wanted to extract the bitmaps out of it. But when I try this with any resource editor it says, not a valid Win32 application or non valid PE file.

So how can I extract the bitmaps out of this .EXE?

Comment: This is probably a violation of the EULA.

Comment: Do you know this for sure?

Comment: I do not have the Windows 98 EULA memorized. You need to go read it yourself. Recent EULAs have a clause saying that the images and sounds can be used only in conjunction with the original OS.

Comment: Are you talking about the card graphics themselves?  If so, they aren't in the Solitaire game but in a DLL called `cards.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). It is free and able to open uncompressed EXE & DLL files.

Comment: I tried, but when opening it with Resource Hacker (or any other Resoure Editor) I get either "Not a valid Win32 application" or "not a PE file". But I can’t find any application that will run on Win98 that helps me getting the resources.

Comment: Try ResourcesExtract, Resource Tuner or PE Explorer. They also doing the same operation.

Comment: "But I can’t find any application that will run on Win98 that helps me getting the resources." - I don't get it. Why do you necessarily have to run Resource Hacker *inside* the VM under Win98? Why can't you run it in Win7 itself?

Answer (score 0):

One can use a combination of `wresttool` and `icotool` on linux to extract icons and pngs, and if you really feel like tearing stuff up, `7z x SOL.EXE` will tear it all apart, and you can find most all image files in .rsc or so.